# Hiding a div using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to hide a div using Javascript, as soon as the page gets loaded in the browser. I am able to do that, if i use the following code :

```
document.getElementById("div_id").style.display='none';
```

But, when i try to do the same thing using JQuery,i notice that the div is visible for a couple of seconds after page loads,and then it becomes hidden. The JQuery code i use is

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#div_id").css('display','none');

});
```

The same thing happens, if i use `$("#div_id").hide();` Is this because im using a library,which would slow down the process a bit,instead of directly using document.getElementById ? . Any way to fix this ?

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, use `$("#div_id").hide();`.  It's more idiomatic for jQuery.

Second, it's because you're using `$(document).ready`.  Usually, that event doesn't fire until the DOM is available for use.  However, because of the way `bindReady()` is implemented, it's possible on some browsers for this event to be equivalent to the `onload` event, which won't fire until **everything** is loaded.  Unfortunately, the only way that I know of to get around this (that doesn't cause problems for disabled users who can't use JavaScript because of a screen reader) is to set a short timeout (say 50ms) and repeatedly check for the existence of `$("#div_id")` while the page is loading.  This is a *horrible* hack, and I hesitate to recommend it, but it should work.  That said, you're almost better off just accepting the flash of content, knowing that most users won't see it.

Comment: Hey, I **did** say it was a horrible hack. :-P

Answer (score 9):

There's an easy solution to this. Set up a CSS class as follows

```
.js #div_id { display: none; }
```

Then have the following jQuery

```
$('html').addClass('js');

$(document).ready(function() {

    /* normal code to run when DOM has loaded here */

});
```

the `<div>` will be hidden immediately (no flashes) if users have JavaScript enabled and won't be if they don't (which circumvents possible [graceful degradation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) problems as [meder points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580300/hiding-a-div-using-jquery/1580319#1580319) in his option c).

This works because when can immediately access the `<html>` element when the page starts to load.

The reason why `document.getElementById("div_id").style.display='none';` is ***probably*** working is because you have it in the `<body>` after the element and therefore the script does not wait for the whole DOM to be loaded before executing.

Comment: No problem. I'm interested to know however, why you first accepted my answer and then accepted another answer, which IMHO, is a much hackier way of achieving your end goal.

Comment: @Russ I was wondering the same thing.   To me this is a better answer.

Comment: +1 This is a much better answer than mine, and should be changed back to the accepted answer.

Comment: @Bob - There's really no need to say that, I'm just curious why the OP changed their mind that's all :)

Comment: Only thing I'd add is, change the name of that class.  `hidden` makes more sense to me than `js` for the class name.

Comment: @Russ - sure there is... it's true.  I didn't even consider this trick, and it's a great one: The `html` element is guaranteed to be available in the DOM if scripts are running, so there's never any need to put that line inside an event handler.

Answer (score 3):

You could either

- a) insert a script element *directly* after the element to hide it with jQuery:
- b) have inconsistent Javascript by directly using DOM methods like your first code snippet
- c) hide it with CSS with the disadvantage that for CSS enabled non-JS users they wouldn't be able to see anything

I would choose between A and C, though I'm not sure exactly what you're hiding.

A:

```
<div id="foo"></div>
<script>$('#foo').hide()</script>
```

C:

```
div#foo { display:none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is that the DOM loads progressively and the $(document).ready event is waiting for the DOM to be *fully* loaded before executing.

If you really want the element to be invisible when the page loads, can you define that style in your CSS instead?

I haven't tried this, but if you still want the div to be visible for non-Javascript users then I think you could do something like this:

```
<noscript>
  <style type="text/css">
  #elementid {display: block !important;}
  </style>
</noscript>
```

Comment: Not the entire page, just the DOM.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Steve. But, why is it that the same problem does not happen when i use document.getElementById instead ?
Also, i can set the style using css. But of the clients browser has javascript disabled then there would be no way he could see the div.
Am i right ?

Comment: samj, when you called document.getElementById() were you calling it inside the $(document.ready) event?  If so, then I don't know why it would be any different really.

Comment: And you are right about non-Javascript users.  Although you could specify an overriding CSS property inside the noscript tag to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

I think a better option would be to style the div so that it is hidden when the page is written, without any javascript.

Then, whenever you are ready to show it again, use javascript to unhide it:

```
$('#someId').show();
```

Comment: This is bad if you're trying to do graceful degradation for users with no JavaScript.

Comment: @BobAman true but he mentions no such requirement / desire.  What if the core functionality of his site requires javascript?   It's a pretty common case these days.

Comment: Perhaps no, but it's something that he should be aware of, regardless.

Answer (score 0):

It might be cause by the way you include the scripts. The browser has to download them before they are run. So if you have a lot of js files this can cause this problem.

Answer (score -1):

More likely it's because you are waiting until the document is ready to hide it.  This seems more like a job for server side script if you want it hidden by default.